# Making part of image transparent

Tags: java, image, graphics, javafx, transparency

I am making a baseball playing application using javafx. I want to display a baseball player on top of a baseball field. However, there is a white box bounding the player and blocking view of the baseball field. **How can I remove this box using javafx?**

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BaseballView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        String image = this.getClass().getResource("baseball_field.jpg")
            .toExternalForm();
        root.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url('" + image + "');  "
            + "-fx-background-position: center center; "
            + "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 340, 340));
        stage.setTitle("Baseball");
        ImageView player = new ImageView();
        player.setTranslateX(250);

        player.setImage(new Image("player.bmp"));
        root.getChildren().add(player);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PNG](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) file format if you want transparency in your images. [BMP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Bitmap) is very limited and hardly supported anywhere in that regard.

Comment: I can change the file type to just about anything. The picture I had downloaded was a bmp. I can use paint to change the file type.

Comment: Don't change it to "anything", change it to PNG and keep the transparency. BMP is very limited, e. g. only 32 bit BMP images support transparency. And then there's the need for the image readers to support that. Also, if you want help on that specific image, you should put the image into your question, since that's the problem.

Comment: The original image has white space.

Comment: Then make the white space transparent with a paint program.

Comment: My question is how to do that with javafx.

Comment: You need an image with a transparent background. A white background in the image is and will remain white.